# Incrementar valor de un documento luego de una inserción

Tags: nodejs, mongodb

Tengo una API NodeJS que utilizo para realizar consultas a una base de datos MongoDB.
Tengo dos colecciones, `Escuelas` e `Inasistencias`, cada documento de `Inasistencias` tiene asociado una única `Escuela` como muestra la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy intentando incrementar los contadores `cant_faltas`, `hombres` y `mujeres` de la colección `Escuelas` cada vez que se inserta un documento en la colección `Inasistencias`

Utilizando los middlewares que provee mongoose realice lo siguiente:

```
Inasistencias.post('save', async function(doc, next){
    
    try{
        
        let escuela = await Escuelas.findById(doc.escuela)

        if(doc.sexo == "MUJER"){

            escuela.data.cat_faltas = escuela.data.cat_faltas + 1;
            escuela.data.mujeres =  escuela.data.mujeres + 1;

        }else if(doc.sexo == "HOMBRE"){

            escuela.data.cat_faltas = escuela.data.cat_faltas + 1;
            escuela.data.hombres =  escuela.data.hombres + 1;

        }

        await escuela.save();

        next()

    }catch(err){
        next(new Error("Ocurrio un error"))
    }


})
```

No creo que sea la forma mas optima de realizarlo, me gustaría saber si hay algún método que permita realizar esta clase de operación o alguna forma mas eficiente de realizarlo.

Comment: ¿Existe un **campo de referencia** de la colección Escuelas dentro de la colección Inasistencias? Por ejemplo `idEscuela`, saludos.

Comment: Sisi, existe, no lo agregue porque esta implícito en la flecha que relaciona ambos esquemas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PROBLEMA**

Se desea incrementar un valor de un campo en un documento cada vez que se inserte documentos en otra colección de la base de datos.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Lo primero que haré es pedirte que hagas un esfuerzo para que saques de tu mente el [modelo relacional](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modelo_relacional) de los datos. La pregunta la inicias mostrando un esquema [ER](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modelo_entidad-relaci%C3%B3n) (entidad - relación), cosa que no tiene nada que ver o hacer en una base de datos [*noSQL*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL).

En el caso de [MongoDB](https://mongodb.com), nos encontramos ante una base de datos [*documental*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL#Bases_de_datos_documentales) o basada en documentos, y en la misma se sustituye el concepto de *relación* por el concepto de *referencia*, siendo esta a otro documento en la misma colección o en otra colección diferente, incluso de otra base de datos.

En cuanto a tu duda concreta, te enfrentas a 2 grandes desafíos:

- Consistencia de datos
- Atomicidad de operaciones

La forma en que actualizas los campos del documento de escuela, basado en el documento insertado de inasistencia, tiene el problema de no ser una operación atómica.

Si durante el proceso de inserción de datos en la colección de inasistencias, (`save`) ocurriese un error al actualizar los campos de la colección de escuelas, no veo que tengas una forma de revertir el proceso de inserción para dejar la base de datos en un estado consistente. Para evitar esto, tendrías que realizar una [*transacción*](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.0/core/transactions/).

Lo que yo propongo es diferente a lo que tienes como modelo de datos, y es simplemente eliminar la dependencia que estás creando en el modelo de escuela al almacenar la cantidad de inasistencias dentro del mismo. Debemos dejar que el motor de Base de Datos se encargue de este asunto, mediante una consulta a la colección de inasistencias. Si deseo la cantidad de inasistencias de una escuela, lo ideal es consultar la colección de inasistencias y no la colección de escuelas. Por otro lado, si deseo obtener la cantidad de inasistencias al momento de consultar una escuela, puedo simplemente traer los datos adicionales mediante un proceso de agregación o una segunda consulta interna. De esta forma no tienes porqué auto incrementar valores manualmente ni preocuparte por la consistencia de los datos al realizar inserciones o actualizaciones.

Usando tu esquema actual, podrías implementar un [método de instancia](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#methods) que se encargará de mostrar la información para la escuela que estás consultando.

Por ejemplo:

```js
// El esquema
const EscuelaSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  nombre: String,
  telefono: String,
  codigo: String
});

//Método de instancia para obtener las inasistencias
EscuelaSchema.method('obtenerInasistencias', function(cb) {
  Inasistencia.find({escuela: this._id}, (error, inasistencias) => {
    if(error) return cb(error);
    const total = inasistencias.length;
    let hombres = inasistencias.filter(inasistencia => inasistencia.sexo === 'masculino').length;
    let mujeres = inasistencias.filter(inasistencia => inasistencia.sexo === 'femenino').length;
    cb(null, {total, hombres, mujeres});
  });
});

// creamos el modelo
const Escuela = mongoose.model('Escuela', EscuelaSchema);

// Consultamos una escuela
Escuela.findById(id)
.then(escuela => {
  if(!escuela) {
    // caso de que la escuela no exista
  }
  console.log(escuela);
  //obtenemos las inasistencias para la escuela consultada
  escuela.obtenerInasistencias((error, inasistencias) => {
    console.log(`Total de inasistencias: ${inasistencias.total}`);
    console.log(`Inasistencias hombres: ${inasistencias.hombres}`);
    console.log(`Inasistencias mujeres: ${inasistencias.mujeres}`);
    // ...
  });
})
.catch(errorHandler)
```

Con esto, tienes una forma de consultar las inasistencias de acuerdo a la escuela consultada en el momento. Obviamente, la consulta realizada te dará las inasistencias en el momento de la consulta, por lo tanto, no existe ambigüedad ni inconsistencia de datos.

En el ejemplo propuesto, el documento de inasistencia tiene una referencia al documento de escuela a través del campo `escuela`, por ejemplo:

```js
//esquema de inasistencia
const InasistenciaSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  nombre: String,
  motivo: String,
  sexo: String,
  escuela: {
    type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Escuela'
  }
}, { collection: 'inasistencias', timestamps: {createdAt: 'created', updatedAt: 'updated'} });
```

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema planteado, que originalmente era auto incrementar un valor basado en una inserción de documentos en otra colección. Lo cual no es lo más recomendable según lo expuesto en la respuesta.

**EDICIÓN**

De acuerdo a tu [comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/387494/incrementar-valor-de-un-documento-luego-de-una-inserci%c3%b3n/388039#comment695501_388039), entiendo que deseas consultar varias escuelas y obtener el resultado de las inasistencias para cada una. Es algo muy sencillo de lograr, ya que cada documento devuelto por una consulta tipo `find()` (que devuelve todas las coincidencias según el filtro o todos los documentos si el filtro es nulo), es una instancia del modelo `Escuela`. Por lo tanto, podemos obtener la lista de inasistencia para cada escuela devuelta por la consulta.

Por ejemplo:

```js
Escuela.find() // <- devuelve una lista con todas las escuelas
.then(escuelas => {
  // creamos un Array de Promesas
  Promise.all(
    escuelas.map(escuela => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        escuela.obtenerInasistencias((error, inasistencias) => {
          if(error) return reject(error);
          return resolve(inasistencias);
        });
      });
    })
  )
  .then(inasistenciasPorEscuela => {
    inasistenciasPorEscuela.forEach((inasistencia, index) => {
      console.log(`Inasistencias para escuela ${escuelas[index].nombre}:`);
      console.log(`Total: ${inasistencia.total}`);
      console.log(`Hombres: ${inasistencia.hombres}`);
      console.log(`Mujeres: ${inasistencia.mujeres}`);
      console.log('----------------------------------------------');
    });
  })
  .catch(errorHandler);
})
.catch(errorHandler);
```

Con esto tienes una forma de obtener las inasistencias de cada escuela que sea consultada con el método `find()`. Y si no pasas ningún filtro, tendrás las inasistencias de cada escuela de tu colección.

Nuevamente hago hincapié en que esta consulta la deberías realizar sobre la colección de inasistencias y no sobre la colección de escuelas.

Por ejemplo, usando un proceso de agregación, y teniendo un campo llamado `escuela` que contiene una referencia a un documento de la colección de escuelas, puedes usar el siguiente proceso de agregación para consultar todas las inasistencias y agruparlas por escuela:

```js
// creamos el array de etapas de agregación
let aggr = [
  {$lookup: {from: 'escuelas', localField: 'escuela', foreignField: '_id', as: 'dataEscuela'}},
  {
    $group: {
      _id: '$escuela', 
      escuela: {$last: '$dataEscuela'},
      total: {$sum: 1},
      hombres: {
        $accumulator: {
          init: function() {
            return {count: 0}
          },
          accumulate: function(state, tipo) {
            let add = 0;
            if(tipo === 'masculino') {
              add = 1;
            }
            return {count: state.count + add}
          },
          accumulateArgs: ['$sexo'],
          merge: function(state1, state2) {
            return {count: state1.count + state2.count}
          },
          finalize: function(state) {
            return state.count;
          },
          lang: 'js'
        }
      },
      mujeres: {
        $accumulator: {
          init: function() {
            return {count: 0}
          },
          accumulate: function(state, tipo) {
            let add = 0;
            if(tipo === 'femenino') {
              add = 1;
            }
            return {count: state.count + add}
          },
          accumulateArgs: ['$sexo'],
          merge: function(state1, state2) {
            return {count: state1.count + state2.count}
          },
          finalize: function(state) {
            return state.count;
          },
          lang: 'js'
        }
      },
    }
  }
];

// obtenemos el resultado del proceso sobre el modelo de inasistencia
Inasistencia.aggregate(aggr)
.then(inasistencias => {
  insistencias.forEach(inasistencia => {
    console.log(inasistencia);
  });
})
.catch(errorHandler);
```

Si queremos las inasistencias de una sola escuela podemos usar una etapa `$match` en nuestra agregación:

```js
let aggr = [
  { $match: { escuela: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id) } }, // debemos usar ObjectId para hacer el `cast` adecuado
  // ...
];
```

Y si queremos las inasistencias de un grupo de escuelas (no todas), podemos usar el operador [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/index.html) al cual le pasaremos un `Array` con objetos de tipo `ObjectId` que representan los valores `_id` de cada escuela. Por ejemplo:

```js
// convertimos una lista de id's en objetos ObjectId
let escuelasPorConsultar = [<Id 1>, <Id 2>, ..., <Id n>];
let ids = escuelasPorConsultar.map(id => { return mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id) });

let aggr = [
  {$match: { escuela: {$in: ids} } },
  // ...
];
```

Comment: Gracias @Mauricio Contreras por responder, quería consultarte si hay alguna forma de realizar un `populate` y que devuelva el `total`, `hombres` y `mujeres` porque de esta forma solo se realiza cuando ejecutas el `findById`

Comment: @NicolasCavilla he editado mi respuesta para añadir la forma de hacerlo sobre varias escuelas a la vez. La verdad que es una consulta bastante sencilla, y aunque el proceso de agregación que puse al final parece muy elaborado, la verdad es que es un proceso muy sencillo para agrupar y contar documentos de la colección de inasistencias. Saludos

Comment: se puede usar el metodo pre save?

Comment: @MauricioContreras gracias por tu aporte! me impulso a estudiar los métodos de instancias.  Con respecto a realizar la consulta sobre las `Escuelas` o sobre las `Inasistencias` , mi idea era "cachear" los datos estadísticos en las `Escuelas` para obtenerlos con un único `find()` ya que me parece que calcular todos estos datos cada vez que realizo un `find()` es muy costoso. Que opinas al respecto? seria preferible ejecutar un evento cada X tiempo y que actualice las estadisticas para reducir costo?